# c# Renci sshnet SFTP client connection behind proxy timeout

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sftp, http-proxy

I am unable to use the below code to connect a SFTP behind a http proxy.  With the same parameters from my config class "ftp" (not provided here for security purposes...) I am able to connect from FileZilla client though...any help guys? Appreciated for your help!!

> at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketReadLine(String& response)    at
>   Renci.SshNet.Session.ConnectHttp()    at
>   Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()    at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
>   at XMLCreator.Common.Utils.SFTPUpload(ftpHandler ftp) in
>   c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\Common\Utils.cs:line 196    at
>   XMLCreator.Common.Utils.UploadFile2FTP(String fileName, FTPModel
>   model) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\Common\Utils.cs:line 168    at
>   XMLCreator.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplication2\Program.cs:line 69

```
var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(ftp.user, ftp.pass));
Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo sftpConn = new    Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo(ftp.host, ftp.port, ftp.user, ProxyTypes.Http, ftp.HttpProxyHost, ftp.HttpProxyPort, ftp.HttpProxyUser, ftp.HttpProxyPass, methods.ToArray());
sftpConn.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
sftpClient2 = new SftpClient(sftpConn);
    using (sftpClient2)
    {                
      //sftpClient2.Connect();
      ((BaseClient)sftpClient2).Connect();
    }
```

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: My network enviornment is bit specific as it uses a customized firewall login format for proxy. Eventually I have to change it to WinSCP which they are able to support.